# How i can make point in coordinates from lat long

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have a working system with Google map API v2. I need migrate it on v3. I use some projections and point, which stored in own projection. So i need convert this points to latlong. How i can do this? Or i need set some options in the map and use needed projection?

for example I have point with coordinates x: 332525.708620, y: 389976.561487 in 27700 projection.

Answer (score -1):

Use these functions...

```
fromPointToLatLng()
fromLatLngToPoint()
```